# Boost.Test howto create "test dependency"

Tags: c++, boost-test

I'm using boost.test as test suite. I want to know if is possible make some prerequisite for test. For example

```
uniqut_ptr< MyClass > g_class;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test1 )
{
    BOOST_REQUIRE_NO_THROW( g_class = CreateMyClass() );
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test2 )
{
    // This test need the test1 as passed
    BOOST_REQUIRE( g_class->doSomething() );
}
```

In this case if test1 fail program will crash in test2. I know that I can add `BOOST_REQUIRE( g_class )` at the begining of each test. But is there another way?

Comment: Unit tests should not depend on the order of execution. This is not a limitation of Boost.Test, but a principle of unit testing in general. To factor out common stuff, you may want to use fixtures

Comment: But is test1 always executed first of test2 right?

Comment: I guess so, but you should not rely on it. You should write your tests in a way that they would work no matter what the order of execution is

Comment: Unless I invoke it with the random switch - which is a good thing to try from time to time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the boost `REQUIRE` for use when you require something to be true, so put the require at the top of each test.
Or consider using a test fixture and do the setup in the setup function. There are examples [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/fixture.html)
It smells like you are trying to use a global variable in your test, so they might interact in horrible ways. Global data is more trouble than it's worth.